# vba Run-time error '424' Object Rrequired

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), trying to copy content from one workbook to master.xlsx

But keep getting the error `424' Object Required`.

Please help me out with this simple question.

```
Sub Submittomaster()    
    Dim Master As Workbook        
    Set Master = Workbook.Open("C:\Users\Elson\Documents\RR\VBA\Tutorial from youtube\master.xlsx")        

    counter = 1

    Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value = ""

    Master.Sheets("sheet1").Range(counter & ":" & counter).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range(counter & ":" & counter).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range(counter & ":" & counter).Value = ""
    counter = counter + 1
    Loop

    Master.Save
    Master.Close
End Sub
```

Thanks to those who can help.

Comment: It's `Workbooks.Open()`

Comment: Also another tip... `.Range(counter & ":" & counter)` can be written as `.Rows(Counter)`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an "s" in your `Set Master` statement. It should be like

```
Set Master = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Elson\Documents\RR\VBA\Tutorial from youtube\master.xlsx")
```